# Sitecore Duplicate Sublayouts/Controls after adding standard values presentation

Tags: sitecore

I have added a control to a specific placeholder in the standard values section of an item's template. The problem is that older items that already have this control in the same placeholder now have duplicate controls in the same placeholder because of the standard values. Is there a way to either remove the duplicate control from the item or only allow these standard values to be used when new items are created?

Comment: Did you try to reset presentation details for these items with duplicate controls?

Comment: Well there are hundreds of these items that would need their presentation details reset.

Comment: No easy solution here, but i could suggest that you create a new template that inherits that template, and add your control to it's standard value, then you can create pages of that template